# prove with a probability of at least $1/e$: $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^k a_{i} P_{i}\right\|_2 \geq\left\|P_{1}\right\|_2$ holds

Tags: probability-distributions, norms, gaussian

Let $a_i (i \in\{1...k\})$ be $k$ IID standard Gaussian random variables, $P_i$ are $d$-dimensional constant vectors. How to prove with a probability of at least $1/e$,
$$
\left\|\sum_{i=1}^k a_{i} P_{i}\right\|_2 \geq\left\|P_{1}\right\|_2 .
$$
holds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\newcommand\si\sigma$Let
$$p:=P\Big(\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^k a_i P_i\Big\| \ge\|P_1\|\Big).$$
Here $\|\cdot\|:=\|\cdot\|_2$.

The inequality $p\ge1/e=0.367\dots$ does not hold in general.

Actually, the best lower bound on the probability $p$
is
$$p_*:=P(|a_1|\ge1)=0.317\dots,$$
which is $<1/e=0.367\dots$.

Indeed, on the one hand, if $P_1\ne0=P_2=\cdots=P_k$, then clearly $p=p_*$. So, there is no lower bound on $p$ that is $>p_*$.

On the other hand, there is a unit $d$-dimensional vector $u$ such that $u\cdot P_1=\|P_1\|$, where $\cdot$ denotes the dot product. Then
$$\Big\|\sum_{i=1}^k a_i P_i\Big\|\ge\Big|u\cdot\sum_{i=1}^k a_i P_i\Big|
=\Big|\sum_{i=1}^k c_i a_i\Big|=|X|, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $c_i:=u\cdot P_i$ and $X:=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i a_i$, so that $c_1=\|P_1\|$. Without loss of generality (wlog), $\|P_1\|\ne0$ -- otherwise, $p=1$. So, by rescaling, wlog $\|P_1\|=1$ and hence $c_1=1$. So, $X$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance
$$\si^2:=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i^2=1+\sum_{i=2}^k c_i^2\ge1.$$
So, in view of \eqref{1},
$$p\ge P(|X|\ge1)=P(\sqrt{\si^2}\,|a_1|\ge1)\ge P(|a_1|\ge1)=p_*.$$

This concludes the proof that $p_*$ is the best lower bound on $p$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: That's brilliant! Thanks a lot mate!